# I want to find the most connected node as a network object in r

Tags: r

I am new to R, I have the data faux.magnolia.high that is in library statnet 
I want find to find the most connected node, then remove all its neighborhood edges , iv tried 
with this code below but I got error , any idea?
for most connected node, should take both in and out degree?

the error is 
Error in degree(fmh, cmode = "indegree") : 
  unused argument (cmode = "indegree")

```
library(statnet)
data(faux.magnolia.high)
fmh <- faux.magnolia.high
degreedist(faux.magnolia.high)

Degree <- degree(fmh, cmode="indegree")     #Computing the in-degree of each node
```

Comment: You say that you got an error. Please show us the error message and tell us which statement caused that error.

Comment: the Error is : Error in degree(fmh, cmode = "indegree") : 
  unused argument (cmode = "indegree")

Comment: Odd. I do not get that error from your code.

Comment: do you know any other solution?

Comment: Since I am not getting that error, I am guessing that you have some sort of package conflict. Try closing R, opening an all new session and run only the code hat you provided in your question.

Comment: yes , now this function works , after re opening, but the answer  did not give me the most connected node, it just calculated all in degree per node, do you know how can find the most connected node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running your code, try

```
table(Degree)
Degree
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8 
524 403 271 128  85  30  13   5   2
```

You can see that the maximum degree is 8 and two nodes have that degree. To find which those nodes are, just use:

```
which(Degree == 8)
[1] 765 991
```

Comment: do you think that for finding most connected node , should i remove indegree right? and finding total?

Comment: I would be gratful for your help,  how can i modify this
function delete.edges (fmh, get.edgeIDs(net, 2, neighborhood = "in")) to use after all  code to delete all neighborhood edges of the most centered node

Comment: I think that you just want `fmh2 = delete.edges (fmh, get.edgeIDs(fmh, 765, neighborhood = "in"))`

Comment: sorry , why shouldn't we delete 991 also?

Comment: If you want to delete _all_ nodes with maximum degree,  you should.

Comment: YES i want to delete  all the most centered neighborhood edges..

Comment: So just run the same code again only replacing 765 with 991